# Angular5, Interaction between components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-components

Currently following a Angular5 course and after doing research for some time on the topic I still don't understand the following fully:

### Code:

App.component.html:

```
      <app-server-element 
      *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
      [element]="serverElement"
       ></app-server-element>
```

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server', name:'Testserver',content:'just a test!'},
                    {type: 'server', name:'Testserver',content:'just a test!'}
];  
   }
```

server-element.component.html:

```
  <p>
    <strong *ngIf="element.type === 'server'" style="color: red">
{{ element.content }}</strong>
    <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
  </p>
```

server-element.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() element: {type:string, name:string, content:string};
}
```

### Question:

I'm a bit confused what this part does:

```
  *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
  [element]="serverElement"
```

In my current understanding it is a for loop which loops through all the elements of the serverElementsArray. But then what does `[element]="serverElement"`do specifically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are totally right about the loop through all elements of `serverElementsArray`.

**Using `[element]=...` you bind the input of component. Read on... :-)**

Notice where is it looped on - `app-server-element` component. I assume that this component is responsible for printing our server detail.

But you have to somehow provide it the server which it should print out. And thats where `[element]=...` comes to play

Notice the `@Input() element` part of `ServerElementComponent`. This defines that component accepts some input value.

So using `[element]=...` you bind a single serverElement to the `@Input` called `element`  in `ServerElementComponent`. There will be multiple `ServerElementComponent`s for each item in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Input method you can communicate between parent-child component only.
And it would become difficult to manage over hierarchy of  parent-child components.
So consider Rxjs event emitter which allows to communicate with sibling components also using common service which reference over [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)